# free() does not work in C

Tags: c

I am trying to free up the memory after using the malloc() function but its not working for me.

```
    //This becomes my header file
    char* staticIP;
    char* start = NULL;
    char* ende = NULL;

    char* splitString(char* start, char* ende) {
    size_t len = ende-start;
    char* result = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(len+1));
    strncpy(result,start,len);
    result[len] = '\0';
    return result;
    }

    //TO free memory
    void freePointer(char* pointer) {
      if (pointer != NULL) {
      free(pointer);
      pointer=NULL;     
     }
    }

    //Function uses splitString which does the malloc 
    void extractIP(char* buffer) {
     char* start = strstr(buffer,"IP=")+3;
     char* ende = strstr(start,":");
     freePointer(staticIP); 
     staticIP = splitString(start,ende);
   } 

    void setupWifi() { 
     char* result = WIFI.getIPString();   
     extractIP(result);
     #ifdef DEBUG 
     USB.print("NEW IP: "); 
     USB.println(staticIP);
     #endif
    }
```

Unfortunately this does not works for me, suggestions/corrections would be appreciated

This the possible use case of my code :

```
    #include<modwifi.h>
    void setup() {
     setupWifi(); 
    }
```

This code is repetitively called after some time interval, static IP gets updated each time which requires that the old static ip gets freed but does not works. I have tried logging the memory after each call but it keeps decreasing till it reaches 0.

This is the possible meaningful code which I could extract out of the big file.

Note: I believe there might be some issue with the start and end as it is declared as pointer but does not uses malloc.

Comment: What do you mean _doesn't work_? How did you test that?

Comment: Please show a test case for your problem, or post the entire code that have the problem.

Comment: Do you mean "not working" because the pointer is not `NULL` after freeing it in `freePointer` and setting it to `NULL` ***locally?*** That value does not find its way back to the caller.

Comment: Yes, when I am trying to log the available memory, it gets reduced on each call and in the end reaches up to 0.

Comment: `//Function uses cut string which does the malloc`...what? Where?

Comment: You mind creating an [___MCVE___](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @AbdulSalamShaikh I don't see any obvious errors in your code, please post an [**MCVE**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Side note: `sizeof(char)` is 1 by definition so you can simply drop it.

Comment: Perhaps the memory leak is coming from `char* result = WIFI.getIPString(); `

Comment: Why did you used the "embedded" tag?

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès maybe because his program is for an embedded system?

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès Just because I am trying to program an environmental sensor. I will be careful with the tags next time.

Comment: It may not be wrong, in embedded env allocation may be specific...

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès Any thoughts on a work around regarding that ?

Comment: There is too many embedded environment...

Comment: @SouravGhosh I have added a MCVE..please take a look

Comment: You free allocated memory _before_ each allocation with `splitString`. After the _last call_ to `splitString` the allocated memory is not `free`'d

Comment: @anita2R It's a never ending loop where the sensor would keep on sending data so there is no last call as such.

Comment: As the memory isn't `free`'d _after_ each use, is the pointer to it going out of scope before the next call. Check that `freePointer` is actually freeing memory or is it just seeing a NULL each time its called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alas on many system logging the available memory of a process doesn't give the expected results. `malloc/free` logically allocates/deallocates memory and does not means that the corresponding memory of the process in the system grows or shrinks accordingly. For efficiency, the system do not behave such because in would be too costly.

Think about a binder with pages. When your process needs space, then the necessary space is searched in the blank pages set currently in the binder, if there is some then your process will used them (logical allocation), if not then you need to add new blank pages to your binder and then use them (physical allocation then logical). When you free memory, corresponding pages are just logically erased (with a logical rubber), but are not returned nor removed.

When you log the memory of a process what you log is the number of pages in your binder...

While it is not impossible to remove the pages from the process space (it depends on the OS), it is not done by standard memory allocation libraries.